# Istio, gRPC, not getting Server Span traces

Tags: java, grpc, istio, opentracing, jaeger

I have Kubernetes cluster with multiple Java services deployed to AWS with Istio. I built a ServerInterceptor where I had the Istio needed B3 headers to the gRPC context. I then implemented a ClientInterceptor where I parse those headers from the gRPC context and insert them into the outgoing headers.

I also implemented OpenTracing Server and Client Tracing Interceptors per: https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-grpc

When I view the traces in the Jaeger UI, all I am seeing is spans reported by the sidecar. They are properly linked as it gets called from service to service, but they are always of type "client." I don't see any of the spans from when I call the database. It seems the context is not transferred from the side car to my actual app. Only sidecar to sidecar to sidecar, etc.

When I run the stack locally in a simple docker compose (without kubernetes and istio) configuration, I see the server spans being created and reported.

How do I get my Java gRPC server to expand on the spans created by the Istio side cars?

Comment: Do you have Jaeger configured to use B3 propagation? See the environment variable `JAEGER_PROPAGATION` mentioned [here](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.12/client-features/) and [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/blob/master/jaeger-core/README.md)